# Как создать продолжение таймера

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создал таймер в игре, работает. При закрытий приложения время сохраняется в `PlayerPrefs`, при новом запуске игры появляется кнопка `Продолжить игру`.

Как при нажатий кнопки `Продолжить игру` продолжить таймер с момента сохранения ?

```
void Update () {
    if (activeTime){ 
        time += Time.deltaTime;
        Minutes.text = Mathf.Floor(time / 60).ToString("000");
        Seconds.text = Mathf.Floor(time % 60).ToString("00");
    }
}


void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString ("TTimeM",Minutes.text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString ("TTimeS",Seconds.text);
}
```

Comment: Предполагаю нужно сконвертировать обратно время, и присвойти для `time ` - ?

Comment: Ну раз вы время сохранили при закрытии, наверное его надо считать при открытии :)

Comment: нет его нужно считать при нажатий на кнопку продолжжить игру ибо пользователь может нажать новая игра и нет смысла считывать, Вопрос как стартануть таймер с места остановки

Comment: а в чем проблема? считываешь минуты, секунды, парсишь в int, потом минуты умножаешь на 60 прибавляешь секунды, получаешь свой time в секундах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос в том чтобы продолжить таймер...Не Создать...
Вот как решил, понимаю что можно было лучше но ... как смог

```
    void Update () {
            if (activeTime){ 
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                Minutes.text = Mathf.Floor(time / 60).ToString("000");
                Seconds.text = Mathf.Floor(time % 60).ToString("00");
            }
    }
    public void ContinueButton(bool isCont){
        if (isCont) {
            time = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("TTimeFloats");
        }
    }
    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("TTimeFloats",time);
    }
```

Comment: public void GetStatusButton(bool isContinue)
    {
        if(!isContinue) time = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("TimeCount");
    }

Comment: Тут задача если нажата кнопка `CONTINUE` - то продолжается таймер если нажато `NEW GAME `- то стартуем заного таймер в этом и суть  `ELSE`

Comment: `activeTime` - Активирует таймер а дальше `if ` проверяет какой таймер запускать

Comment: Нужно больше копипаст кода) и 10 вложенных if )   На самом деле у тебя логическая ошибка в названии переменных, ты в тот же newGame кладешь Continue, то есть у тебя новая игра, когда продолжение)  + ты каждый кадр делаешь не нужный if с проверкой newGame. Меняй таймер в момент смены состояния newGame/Continue в функции public void GetStatusButton(bool isContinue);

Comment: @Xumera_hZ  поменял немного логику спасибо за совет про постоянную проверку, таймер я запускаю с другого класса `timerK.GetComponent<TimerHandler>().activeTime = true;` , надеюсь так лучше ))

Comment: Совсем другое дело)